# how do I use rewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect some urls to pretty urls and the thing is that I'm new to this so I can't seem to figure out what part I did wrong
this is the htaccess right now but the rewrite rule is not working.

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ -
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([.]+)/([.]+)$ index.php?search_categories%5B%5D=$1&search_location=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Give us an example of a URL you want to rewrite, and a proper problem description - "not working" is not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/(.+)$ index.php?search_categories=$1&search_location=$2 [QSA,L]
```

In your rule you have: `search_categories%5B%5D`, may be a mistake while copy/paste I removed the `%5B%5D` even this is not the problem

`^(.+[^/])/(.+)$` match `category/location` the rule `[^/]` is to not match the slash `/`

**EDIT:**

It can also simplified with just: `^([^/]*)/(.*)$`

In your code `[.]+` the dot match `Any single character` but brackets is used for range like `[abc]` will match a, b or c, so it will not work with just `[.]+`, also like I wrote before you have to not match the slash with `[^/]` this last one must be inside brackets, more [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) and [Cheat Sheet](https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/)

Test [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=fa65efa4-fe0b-49be-b9bb-e0384bf8d609)

Comment: Thank you so much that actually worked but can someone explain more why the previous one didn't worked?

Comment: Glad it worked! `[.]+` the dot match `Any single character` but brackets is used for range like `[abc]` will match a, b or c, also you have to not match the slash with `[^/]`, more [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html)